# Element in a series takes on a different value when assigned to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am really puzzled by this... I have an existing DataFrame and when I assign a series of values (of the same length) to a new column somehow the last element in the series takes on a different value when in the DataFrame. This code

```
    print('Standalone 2nd to last: ' + series.iloc[-2])
    print('Standalone last: ' + series.iloc[-1])
    delta['Etf'] = series
    print('In a frame 2nd to last: ' + delta['Etf'].iloc[-2])
    print('In a frame last: ' + str(delta['Etf'].iloc[-1]))
```

produces this output:

```
Standalone 2nd to last: ZHY CN
Standalone last: IBDB US
In a frame 2nd to last: ZHY CN
In a frame last: nan
```

I appreciate any explanation of this.

Comment: Can you post `series` here along with your question, please? Also, please add what your expected output should look like

Comment: Does the index of series match the index of delta exactly? If not, when you use delta['Etf'] = series, it will perform a join, matching up on the indices it has available. Consider integer indexing, where delta has 10 items and series has only 5. The final 5 values in delta['Etf'] will all be NaNs as there was no shared index value to match on (while the first 5 values will match what was series)

Comment: emmet02, you're right, the index was off for the last row in the existing was different. Thanks!

Comment: @emmet02 in addition, even if they are the same length, you can have this problem if the indices are in different order.

Answer (score 0):

Per @emmet02 comment, the index of the data frame was different from the one in the series and hence they did not align perfectly